# cant make the gmaps.js search functions

Tags: search, gmaps.js

i have made this simple app with gmaps.js but i need the search functions like they show it here:

http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html

i looked at the source code and all but it aint working.. The search button reloads the page...

my code is a follows:

```
<script>
    $('#geocoding_form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        GMaps.geocode({
          address: $('#address').val().trim(),
          callback: function(results, status){
            if(status=='OK'){
              var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
            }
          }
        });
      });
</script>


<form method="post" id="geocoding_form">
          <label for="address">Address:</label>
          <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
          </div>
        </form>

<div id="map"></div>
```

the rest is loaded in from scripts.js you can see it in sourcecode. Why is this happening and how can i fix this?

The web app is located here, http://travelers.work/trein/

Comment: I also have this in a pen without the search function, so it might be better to look at the code.. http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/JGXoVJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
```

to

```
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

because the search returns a `LatLng` object as a result, and that's what is needed as an input for `setCenter`.

Here's a JS demo with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/DuRhR/3/

EDIT after comments:

Alternatively, you can pass to `setCenter` a [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral)

```
map.setCenter({lat: latlng.lat(), lng: latlng.lng()});
```

Comment: Can you show me this on the codepen i made? codepen.io/shiva112/pen/JGXoVJ

Comment: Your codepen works perfectly. Type the name of a city in the search field, for instance "new york" (with or without quotation marks), and you will see that the map re-centers at that location.

Comment: Actually, no. This is per documentation :)

Comment: Both `lat` & `lng` are actually functions, and it doesn't expect an object, but 2 different properties, hence the `,`